# Apps Script: Add field to formobject

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

[image]

I have an apps script template in a sidebar with a form (screenshot).

```
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">

           <div id="texts">


    </div>



        <div>
            <label for="optionList">Click me</label>
            <select id="optionList" ondblclick = "addText(event)" name="optionList" size="5">
</select>

        </div>

        <br>



        <br>

        <div>

            <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>

        </div>
        <div id="textboxes"></div>

        <div id="insert"></div>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>
```

When its created, it receives a row of sheets data that looks like:

```
var jsonRow = <?= row ?>; //PASSED IN JSON
```

When the form is submitted I understand that a formobject is created which is passed back to the server side. I'd like to add the jsonRow to the formobject so as to allow for processing on the server side.

What's the best way to do this? The code to submit the form is below:

```
        function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
                    console.log('handleFormSubmit')
        console.log(formObject)

        console.log(jsonRow)
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).processRowPopupHTML(formObject);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the values of both `formObject` and `jsonRow` at a function `processRowPopupHTML()` of GAS side.
- In your HTML, you want to retrieve the values from SelectElement and TextAreaElement.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several solutions for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

In this modification, the values from SelectElement and TextAreaElement are retrieved at Javascript side and send as a object to GAS side by adding `jsonRow`.

#### Modified script:

Please modify `handleFormSubmit()` as follows.

```
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
  console.log('handleFormSubmit')
  console.log(formObject)
  console.log(jsonRow)

  // Added this object
  const response = {
    jsonRow: jsonRow,
    formObject: {
      optionList: formObject.optionList.value,
      message: formObject.message.value,
    }
  };

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).processRowPopupHTML(response);
}
```

#### Result:

You can retrieve the following object at the function `processRowPopupHTML()` of GAS side.

```
{
  "jsonRow": "### values ###",
  "formObject": {
    "optionList": "### values ###",
    "message": "### values ###"
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that in your script, `console.log(jsonRow)` correctly shows the value of `jsonRow`.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.